# SVG is hidden in iOS build from codemagic

Tags: flutter, dart, codemagic

I have several SVGs in my app working perfectly fine, but two of them making trouble.
They are shown in the simulator and also on a release build on a real device, but in the build from codemagic distributed via TestFlight they are gone.

Is there any way to find out what is happening?

here is the code:

```
children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                  if (!checkBoxValue)
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setCheckbox();
                      },
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/icons/checkbox-unchecked.svg",
                          width: 12,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  else
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setCheckbox();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/icons/checkbox-checked.svg",
                          width: 12,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Here is one example:
[codemagic build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUB0L.jpg)
[local build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apBOd.png)

Comment: try renaming the icons to use underscore instead of hyphen in the name. Might be something to do with how iOS bundles files.

Comment: Thanks, will try it! But other files with hyphen are working.